# Need Documentation or API on Bluetooth Connectivity between Polytel Glucose Meter Adapter With Android Application

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have a task to develop an android application that will communicate with a glucose meter via bluetooth.The glucose meter is connected to a bluetooth adapter which will be responsible for transmitting the glucose results via bluetooth to the android application.

The first challenge i have is that i have not been able to get any documentation that specifies the data format that the glucose meter sends the results in.I have no idea how to parse the result,because i do not know the information contained in the test result.

The bluetooth adapter manual i googled had no developer guide/API that i was able to discover.

Can anyone who has done similar work point me towards any documentation/materials that will aid me in developing the application?

The medical equipment i have to work with are:

```
            One touch ultra2 glucose meter
            Polytel GMA(Glucose Meter Adapter)– Polymap wireless model: PWR-09-02
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you contacted Polytel?